# Keep anchors links on printing html page

Tags: html, css, angular, hyperlink, anchor

I'm using angular, and we're defining the printed page style in CSS using:

```
@media print {
   ...
}
```

Then, using `Ctrl + p` we can save the page to pdf.

The problem is that the anchors (`<a>`) don't work on the PDF.

I've searched anywhere but I can't find any solution.

Any ideas? Thanks!

BTW, https://stackoverflow.com/ succeeded to do so (press `Ctrl + p`, save to pdf, open and you'll see that the links are working) but I didn't locate how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out.

The links aren't working when there're directing to `http://` and not `https://` which happened in my case cause I was testing it on localhost.

Hope someone will find it useful